# Calling a random number generating member function doesn't produce entirely random numbers

Tags: c++, random, wxwidgets

I'm creating a wxWidget application with C++ where at the start of the program I want the application window to contain pixels with random colors like this:

[image: Random coloured pixels]

In the above application there are 3600 pixels (60 x 60) and I have given each pixel a random RGB color by using `uniform_int_distribution`

The colours for the pixels in the image above are generated at the moment using the following function in my code:

```
void random_colors(int ctable[][3], int n)
{
  // construct a trivial random generator engine from a time-based seed:
  unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  std::default_random_engine generator (seed);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,255);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
      for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
      {
        ctable[i][j] = distribution(generator);
      }
  }
}
```

I do this by giving this function a table with dimensions 3600 x 3 and this function will fill in the values for the colours.

This way however is not what I want. What I want is to create a class called `somNode` where each `somNode`-object represents a pixel in the picture (with RGB values as a member array attribute). In this `somNode`-class I have a member function using `uniform_int_distribution` to give when constructed each `somNode` its own random RGB colour. This is the function which creates the random colour for each `somNode`:

```
void rand_node_colour(int nodeWeights[])
{
  // construct a trivial random generator engine from a time-based seed:
  unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  std::default_random_engine generator (seed);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,255);
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    nodeWeights[i] = distribution(generator);
  }
}
```

the `nodeWeights` member array represents the RGB-value of the `somNode`. Now when I create this "som-grid" what I have in the image above (the 3600 pixels corresponding to 3600 `somNode`s) I use the following code (take a look at the som-constructor):

```
#include "somNode.h"
#include <vector>

class som
{
    public:
        double learning_rate;
        std::vector<somNode> somGrid;
    public:
        som(double lrate);
        void epoch();
        void trainOnce();

};

/*
* Initialize the som grid
*/
som::som(double lrate)
{
    learning_rate = lrate;
    // Create the som grid
    for(int i=0; i<60; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<60; j++)
        {
            int xL = j*10;
            int xR = (j+1)*10;
            int yT = i*10;
            int yB = (i+1)*10;
            somGrid.push_back(somNode(xL, xR, yB, yT));
        }
    }
}

// Train som by one epoch
void som::epoch()
{

}

// Train som by one color
void som::trainOnce()
{

}
```

So I have a `vector<somNode> somGrid` where I push all these 3600 `somNode`s when I construct them. When each node is constructed the `somNode` member function `rand_node_colour` is called which creates the RGB-value.

When however I implement this code instead of the one I used at first I get this result:

[image]

You can see that there is a clear pattern so something is going wrong here. My question is: What is happening in the random number generation when somNodes are created? Why it doesn't produce the same result as the code I used above?

P.S. here is the `somNode.cpp`:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include<cmath>

void rand_node_colour(int nodeWeights[]);

/*
* This class represent a node in the som-grid
*/
class somNode
{
    public:
        // Weight of the node representing the color
        int nodeWeights[3];
        // Position in the grid
        double X, Y;
        // corner coorinates for drawing the node on the grid
        int x_Left, x_Right, y_Bottom, y_Top;

    public:
        // Constructor
        somNode(int xL, int xR, int yB, int yT);
        void editWeights(int r, int g, int b);
        double getDistance(int r, int g, int b);
};


somNode::somNode(int xL, int xR, int yB, int yT)
{
    // Set the corner points
    x_Left = xL;
    x_Right = xR;
    y_Bottom = yB;
    y_Top = yT;
    // Initialize random weights for node
    rand_node_colour(nodeWeights);
    // Calculate the node's position (center coordinate)
    X = x_Left + (double)((x_Right - x_Left)/double(2));
    Y = y_Bottom + (double)((y_Top - y_Bottom)/double(2));
}

void somNode::editWeights(int r, int g, int b)
{
    nodeWeights[0] = r;
    nodeWeights[1] = g;
    nodeWeights[2] = b;
}

double somNode::getDistance(int r, int g, int b)
{
    return sqrt(pow(nodeWeights[0]-r, 2) + pow(nodeWeights[1]-g, 2) + pow(nodeWeights[2]-b, 2));
}


void rand_node_colour(int nodeWeights[])
{
  // construct a trivial random generator engine from a time-based seed:
  unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  std::default_random_engine generator (seed);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,255);
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    nodeWeights[i] = distribution(generator);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you call `random_colors` or `rand_node_colour` multiple times? If you do it to quickly then multiple calls might use the same seed value.

Comment: Hi @JoachimPileborg yes, every time when a `somNode` is constructed I call the `rand_node_colour`. Take a look at the `somNode` constructor. My idea was to at every construction create random colour for the node.  I see...how could I fix this? :)

Comment: Seed the gen. only once at construction, preferably using a `std::random_device`. See a simple example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: Create only one generator and one distribution object, and use the same all the time. For example, declare them (and the seed) as `static` variables.

Comment: Got it :) I will try the `static` approach. Thank you :)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that you constantly recreate and seed the random number generator in `rand_node_colour`.  You call it in a tight loop so you can get the same time which means the seed will be the same and that means the random numbers generated will be the same.

What you need to do is seed the generator once and then keep using its random output.  An easy way to fix you code would be to make it `static` in the function sos it is only initialized once and each subsequent call to the function will continue on instead of start the generator all over.  If we do that the code becomes

```
void rand_node_colour(int nodeWeights[])
{
  // construct a trivial random generator engine from a time-based seed:
  static std::default_random_engine generator (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,255);
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    nodeWeights[i] = distribution(generator);
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! That did it. And now I also understand why. Thank you =)

Comment: @jjepsuomi No problem.  Glad to help.

Comment: In addition, I must note that `default_random_engine` is going to alias different generators on different platforms and is highly likely to be some subpar generator like LCG. It is better to explicitly state intention to use some concrete generator.